# Java Scanner get a number of input from the users and print out

Tags: java

I am working on a small program. I need to get a number of integers from the user and print them out. I also need to identify whether the input is valid or not. Here is my code:

```
List<Integer> tokens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
  tokens.add(sc.nextInt());
  System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
}
```

My first question is how to identify the type of the input and store this information in a variable.
My second question is I enter an infinite loop when I run the code. After I enter the input, the program prints all of them and then waits for input again. How do I solve this problem?
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: What does `Scanner#nextInt()` do? What does `hasNextInt` do?

Comment: What is an _infinite loop_? What purpose does the boolean you provide to the `while` loop have?

Comment: Hint: Read some tutorials

Comment: If sc.hasNextInt() is true, the program will print the next integer, else the loop will end.

Comment: In SOP it tries to fetch the "next next int" :)

Comment: Could you please explain more? How to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: The input is entered by the user. It can be "1 2 3 4". After I hit enter, it prints the integers and then waits for inputs again. But I want to finish the program after the printing.

Comment: `nextInt()` wants to consume *another int* each time you call it. And you call it twice per loop step. You don't have an infinite loop, you have *blocking* where you don't expect it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

- Why are You calling  `sc.nextInt()` 2 times in the loop without checking for next value?
- Use an invalid number such as `-1` to break the loop.
- Don't forget to close the stream.

sample code:

```
List<Integer> tokens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        if (i == -1) {
            break;
        }
        tokens.add(i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
System.out.println(tokens);
```

Read [Java7- The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> tokens = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String data = "";
        System.out.println("Enter some numbers...");

        while (sc.hasNext()) {

            data = sc.next();

            if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT")) {
                System.out.println();
                break;
            } 

            try {
                tokens.add(Integer.parseInt(data));
                System.out.println(sc.next());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out
                        .println("Error: Your input string cannot be converted to a number.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```